# Putting data from database into charts in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to put data from my database into a Chartjs graph and am unsure how.

My database looks like:

```
GET /dwelling/room/


[
    {
        "room_id": 1,
        "room_name": "Living Room",
        "room_data": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "temperature": "5,15,9..."
                "humidity": "9,3,10..."
                ...
```

I am currently using the code from the MDB react library for the line graph:

```
    const dataLine = {
  labels: ['00:00', '01:00', '02:00', '03:00', '04:00', '05:00', '06:00', '07:00', '08:00', '09:00', '10:00', '11:00', '12:00', '13:00', '14:00', '15:00', '16:00', '17:00', '18:00', '19:00', '20:00', '21:00', '22:00', '23:00'],
  datasets: [
    {
      fill: false,
      lineTension: 0.1,
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(75,192,192,0.4)',
      ...
      pointHitRadius: 10,
      data: [?]
    }
  ]
};
```

I have added a question mark in `data: [?]` because this is where I am wanting to put the data from my database. This is how I am getting the data for other sections:

```
{props.room.map(room => {

                return (

                    <React.Fragment>
                        <div>{room.room_name}<div>
                    </React.Fragment>
                    ...
```

I have tried:

```
var dataSet = {room.room_data[0].temperature}
var dataArray = dataSet.split(',');
...
data: [dataArray]
```

This, however, doesn't work as I am having to declare the variables outside of the map.

I would appreciate any help! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a React binding for Chartjs you could use: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-chartjs-2

Consult Chartjs documentation on the parameters: 
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html#number

This, however, doesn't work as I am having to declare the variables outside of the map. -> What is stopping you from declaring variables inside the map?

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions - I will give them a look. In regards to the declaring them inside the map, when I write, `var dataArray = room.room_data[0].temperature;` in the map, it doesn't show anything on the page. However, when i write, `var dataArray = room.room_data[0].id;`, it shows the id of the data. I don't suppose you would know why this is? I am calling it later in the return() as `<div>{dataArray}</div>`.

Comment: That’s because .temperature is a String and .id is a Number. Get it?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much! I am able to call all the other things in my database but not temperature for some reason so there must be an issue with this in the database.

Comment: Not necessarily. Do you get back all your data in the browser? If you do, it’s not a database problem.

Comment: Turns out the person writing the backend spelt temperature wrong which is why it was causing issues haha.

Comment: Typos happen mate